# How to Change Switch Configuration through Opendaylight controller(GUI)

Tags: mininet, opendaylight, graphical-interaction

I am new to SDN,

Environment- I have 2 VMs(VM Ware) running on my Windows 10(laptop). One is Mininet and another is Opendaylight(in Ubuntu). I made a simple topology through mininet and connected it to the controller and I can see the topology in Opendaylight Controller.

Topology: 3 switches, 4 hosts and 1 controller.[Please click here to see topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCDFg.png)

Question- I know that through controller we can manage the switches, change the configuration, etc. so exactly we can do that through GUI of the controller?

If anyone can guide me through how to do the following step by step.
1. how to block ping from host
2. how to make VLANs or something.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Yang UI](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/sites/site/org.opendaylight.docs/master/userguide/manuals/userguide/bk-user-guide/content/_interacting_with_the_open_daylight_controller_odl.html) to manage the switches in OpenDayLight.

Or you can send PUT requests to ODL;
[This](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe1992/1418c01407d03420c333e8b8ec664f5e) is an example of a PUT request that install a flow on switch "openflow:3" in table 0 that matches flows with source IP 10.0.0.3, destination IP 10.0.0.9 and VLAN id 1. The action modifies the VLAN tag to 2 and resends it in output trough the same port.