# ODL magnesium with Openflow

Tags: linux, windows, sdn, opendaylight, openflow

I want to setup mininet, Openflow plugin with ODL magnesium version where the ODL UI is not supported now.
I need guidance on how can I set this up on my local system and configure it.

The main purpose is that I should get XML payload like it is provided at https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/openflowplugin/en/stable-magnesium/users/operation.html#retrieving-topology-details-by-using-restconf on my postman.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Change Switch Configuration through Opendaylight controller(GUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963167/how-to-change-switch-configuration-through-opendaylight-controllergui)

Answer (score 0):

The UI has nothing to do with setting up and/or configuring openflow or mininet, so
don't worry about that.

You need to start ODL and install the openflowplugin features. probably just
odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest and odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer is good enough.

then start mininet and point it to your running controller. something like

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=<controller_ip> --switch=ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
```

Once that is setup, you should be able to use POSTMAN to interact with your
controller to program and see flows.

Comment: in mininet 2.2.2 the command says ```sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=<controller_ip> --switch=ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13``` some weird set of examples like --mac automatically etc, it feels like it is opening up help command like structure.
Also I want to ask is it okay that my ODL is running on windows and mininet on vmware? will it work on postman. I hope yes.

Comment: check this opened issue https://github.com/mininet/mininet/issues/949

Comment: looks like in the screenshot from the github issue, that you have a space between remote, and ip= That is likely the issue there.  I've never run ODL on windows, so not sure if it will work or not and nothing wrong running mininet on a VM. just make sure the mininet system and the ODL system can ping each other (network connectivity). postman is the same. as long as it has network connectivity to the ODL ip address it will be fine

Comment: Can you use windows with odl and mininet on virtualbox to check flows in postman? 
How can I setup odl and mininet pinging each other in windows platform.Please can you do its setup locally, i tried using putty but I can't see the flows in it using dump command.

Comment: I've never used windows with these things, but I assume you can just bring up two different virtual machines running linux and put ODL in one and mininet in the other. virtualbox could be used for that.